# Kerberos Double Hop Authentication - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows, kerberos

We three application servers and three database servers. We're trying to enable Kerberos authentication between the application servers and the database servers. All of the application servers can successfully connect to two out of the three database servers. The app servers are using Windows 2008 and Windows 2012 with IIS 7.0.

The database servers are using Windows 2012 and SQL Server 2008 R2. We can't figure out what is different between the two SQL Server instances that work and the one that does not. The one that does not appears to not be receiving tokens as it is reporting an anonymous login.

#### Update

Everything is on the same domain. I am using Kerberos in order to allow IIS to impersonate the client user. We have a production app & database server and a test app and database server. We're trying to setup a training/QA app and database server. None of the app servers have any difficulty connecting to either the live or test database servers. All of them fail to connect to the QA database server. We're trying to track down what is different on that server.

Comment: Where does the double hopping come in? An IIS app pool running under a particular set of credentials will typically connect (using that same identity) to SQL Server. This is just a single hop. If you're actually using a double hop of some kind things get real complicated real quick, but from your problem description it sounds like your server has trouble validating the client's login with the domain controller. Speaking of that: is everything in the same domain?

Comment: Do all three accounts run under the same Windows account? For that matter, are they all in the same Windows domain? What do the SPNs look like for the account(s) that are running your SQL Servers?